# Workflow: Email with link to EditForm of lookup field

Tags: workflow, list, email

I have a list called "Alerts" that has a lookup field to "MyEvents". In Sharepoint designer I need to make a workflow that is sending email with a hyperlink pointing directly to EditForm of MyEvents, like:

Alert, event data is missing, please fill the form:
http://myserver/Lists/MyEvents/EditForm.aspx?ID=15

When I click on a hyperlink in email i can select [%Current Item:MyEvents%], but I can not go deeper, to have something like Current Item:MyEvents.ID. It ends with an email with:

```
<a href="214;#Event three 2011">214;#Event three 2011</a>
```

Any idea how to build it as I need with server url and EditForm and ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Workflow Context: Current Site URL, InstanceID,... etc.

Comment: Thanks, in deed in the Workflow Context there are lot of usefull fields to take, so I've ended up with something like: [%Workflow Context:Current Site URL%]/Lists/MyEvents/EditForm.aspx?ID=[%MyEvents:Id%]